# Algebraic way to compute degree of reflection map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider a diagonal matrix
$$
   A = \left. \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
                        0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
                        0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
                        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                        0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
        \end{bmatrix} \right\} n+1
$$
It induces the continuous map $\mathcal{A} \colon S^{n} \to S^{n}$ by the rule
$$
   \mathcal{A}(x) = \frac{Ax}{|Ax|} = Ax,
$$
where $|Ax| = \sqrt{ (Ax)^{T} Ax } = 1$ since $A$ is orthogonal. I want to show that $\deg \mathcal{A} = -1$. It can be done via construction of triangulation of $S^n$ invariant to the action of $\mathcal{A}$ (see [Borisovich et al](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Q9T574)). But is there an algebraic way to prove this? The statement seems more easy than its proof given in the book mentioned above.

Comment: This matrix $A$ is orthogonal. So $|Ax|=|x|$, and with $x$ coming from $S^n$, $|x|=1$. So you really just have $x\mapsto Ax$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a proof using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in paragraph (7) of [this note](http://preschema.com/documents/degrees-of-maps-of-sphere.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This matrix $A$ is orthogonal. So $|Ax|=|x|$, and with $x$ coming from $S^n$, $|x|=1$. So you really just have $x\mapsto Ax$. As a linear transformation, it is leaving every coordinate alone except the first, which is negated.

The degree must be $1$ or $-1$, since the map is one-to-one. You just need to deduce that it is not $1$.

The map leaves the $n-1$ sphere defined by $x_1=0$ alone, and cuts the rest of $S^n$ into two hemispheres that are swapped. If the degree were $1$, this map would have to be equivalent to the identity...

Comment: It isn't an algebraic way. It is a proof given in the book from my post (in book it is more detalized also).

Comment: Oh, well, that's algebraic topology in action, so I thought that's what you mean. Degree is an algebraic topological concept, so what else would you mean by 'algebraically'?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but maybe the use of some properties of degree, functoriality of homology e.t.c.